# Websphere EJB3.0 Timer Avoid Persistence

Tags: timer, persistence, websphere, ejb-3.0

Websphere 7.0, EJB3.0

Is there a way to avoid default EJB timer persistence. Looks like timers survive server crashes and restarts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Non persistent EJB timers added in Java EE 6 (WebSphere 8 and up).

If you need non persistent timers in WebSphere 7 you should probably need to use [AlarmManager](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/asynchbeans/AlarmManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

The preferable way with EJB-3.0 is to clear all timers on server shutdown/startup to avoid timers persisted due to failure.

You can place code in appropriate methods - `onApplicationEnd` or `onApplicationStart` by implementing `ApplicationListener` interface, alternatively you can refer [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21412991), but former is better.

Else, can run the command to explicitly cancel timers as mentioned in documentation.

> **cancelEJBTimers**

```
This command cancels and removes from persistent storage EJB timers based on the specified filter criteria.

The syntax for this command is: cancelEJBTimers server filter [options]    filter: -all | -timer | -app [-mod [-bean ]]
           -all
           -timer timer id
           -app   application name
           -mod   module name
           -bean  bean name

  options: -host  host name
           -port  portnumber
           -conntype connector type
           -user  userid
           -password password
           -quiet
           -logfile filename
           -replacelog
           -trace
           -help
```

In EJB-3.1, with `TimerConfig` you can configure it with `setPersistent(isPersistent)`.